# What kind of API is this? REST or?

Tags: api

Still fairly new to web dev, so I would like to know whether any of you would be able to tell me if the below API is REST or some other type (or no type if that is also an option). I'm taking on learning API as my next step in my web dev education, and I specifically would first like to learn the type of API that would best help me use the below source. I've found different kinds of API courses online (on LinkedIn Learning mostly, where I have a subscription) and a good chunk of them seem focused on REST, so it would nice if the below source is REST as well, but of course it's not required.

https://docs.compulife.com/#612831b4-80e6-4ce8-9863-27a320c97f85

Thanks,
R.

Comment: I recommend you to google "rest api vs" and look at autocompletes. Haha. You can find some counterparts and get some insight.

Comment: it is indeed a REST API.